# Unspecified pixel format during frame extraction

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg

I have the following algorithm to extract a frame from video:

```
def build_extract_frame_cmd(millisecond: int) -> str:
    return (
        "ffmpeg"
        " -i -"  # accept input from stdin
        f" -ss {millisecond}ms"  # seek the position to the specific millisecond
        " -vframes 1"  # only handle one video frame
        " -c:v png"  # select the output encoder
        " -f image2pipe -"  # force output file to stdout
    )


async def run_shell_command(cmd: str, stdin: bytes) -> bytes:
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        *shlex.split(cmd),
        stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
    )

    stdout, stderr = await proc.communicate(input=stdin)

    level = logging.DEBUG if proc.returncode == 0 else logging.WARN
    if stderr:
        LOGGER.log(level, f"[stderr]{stderr.decode()}")
    return stdout
```

but it fails with the following error:

```
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x5622ea6c32c0] stream 0, offset 0x2c: partial file
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x5622ea6c32c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 1 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 1536x1536, 717 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'pipe:':

  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2iso6mp423gp4
    comment         : gml.e45e1268

  Duration: 00:01:00.29, start: 0.262000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 102 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Audio Media Handler
    Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 1536x1536, 717 kb/s, 20 fps, 20 tbr, 1k tbn, 2k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Video Media Handler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> png (native))
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x5622ea6c32c0] stream 1, offset 0xe25: partial file
pipe:: Invalid data found when processing input
Cannot determine format of input stream 0:1 after EOF
Error marking filters as finished
Conversion failed!
```

I'm not sure where to begin troubleshooting, but the above is the console output when I try to execute the command, so hopefully it helps.

Comment: Does this also happen if you run ffmpeg "directly" from the console?

Comment: yes, it does happen

Comment: So this question has *nothing* to do with Python, but rather how a utility program handles a file you have posted no information about.

Comment: @ScottHunter what kind of info about the video I can add so it will be useful?

Comment: Did you "Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options" as suggested?

Comment: @ScottHunter sorry, I just figure out that the ffmpeg command works from console
`ffmpeg -i 7024471845082869736.mp4 -ss 2000ms -vframes 1 -c:v png -f image2pipe output.png`

Comment: Think, why are you are getting the error: *"Cannot determine format of input stream"*? It looks like you are not writing any data to FFmpeg `stdin` pipe. Replace '" -i -"` with '" -i 7024471845082869736.mp4"` and remove `stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE`. Note: writing mp4 file as bytes sequence to `stdin` pipe, usually doesn't work (there is an issue with the "moov atom", that usually positioned at the end of the mp4 file).